# DRBD Failure: (127) Device minor not allocated

Tags: centos, openvz, replication, drbd

I use wmware workstation to run two virtual machines with `OpenVZ 2.6.32-042stab108.2` installed on top on `CentOS 6.6`. I have created another primary partition, `/dev/sda4`, to configure it as drbd resource. I also created a filsystem on it. The second machine is actually created using the virtual disk of the first one, with changed hostname and eth0 ip address. The drbd configuration file is this:

```
global { usage-count no; } 
common { syncer { rate 100M; } } 
resource r0 { 
        protocol C; 
        startup { 
                wfc-timeout  15; 
                degr-wfc-timeout 60; 
        } 
        net { 
                cram-hmac-alg sha1; 
                shared-secret "password"; 
        } 
        on primary { 
                device /dev/drbd0; 
                disk /dev/sda4; 
                address 192.168.18.10:7788; 
                meta-disk internal; 
        } 
        on secondary { 
                device /dev/drbd0; 
                disk /dev/sda4; 
                address 192.168.18.20:7788; 
                meta-disk internal; 
        } 
}
```

After creating the resource with **drbdadm create-md r0**, when I enter **service drbd start**, I get:

```
Failure: (127) Device minor not allocated.
```

The output of **drbdadm dump all** might be helpful:

```
[root@primary ~]# drbdadm dump all
# /etc/drbd.conf
# resource r0 on primary: not ignored, not stacked
resource r0 {
    protocol               C;
    on primary {
        device           /dev/drbd0 minor 0;
        disk             /dev/sda4;
        address          ipv4 192.168.18.10:7788;
        meta-disk        internal;
    }
    on secondary {
        device           /dev/drbd0 minor 0;
        disk             /dev/sda4;
        address          ipv4 192.168.18.20:7788;
        meta-disk        internal;
    }
    net {
        cram-hmac-alg    sha1;
        shared-secret    danuts;
    }
    startup {
        wfc-timeout       15;
        degr-wfc-timeout  60;
    }
}
```

What is causing this error and how can it be mitigated? Thanks!

Comment: Updated with `drbdadm dump all` command output.

Comment: You mean the guest operating system is openvz+centos6.6?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error , it appeared that IP address for the second node was not reachable.
First i checked the service status:

```
systemctl status drbd.service
â drbd.service - DRBD -- please disable. Unless you are NOT using a cluster manager.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/drbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar. 2018-04-10 16:21:49 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 3347 ExecStart=/lib/drbd/drbd start (code=exited, status=20)
 Main PID: 3347 (code=exited, status=20)

avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B systemd[1]: Starting DRBD -- please disable. Unless you are NOT using a cluster manager....
avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B drbd[3347]: Starting DRBD resources: drbd.d/r0.res:20: in resource r0, on GROESSLTCL0B:
avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B drbd[3347]: IP 192.168.254.2 not found on this host.
avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B systemd[1]: drbd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=20/n/a
avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B systemd[1]: Failed to start DRBD -- please disable. Unless you are NOT using a cluster manager..
avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B systemd[1]: Unit drbd.service entered failed state.
avril 10 16:21:49 GROESSLTCL0B systemd[1]: drbd.service failed.
```

So i fixed the IP of the second node in r0.res , the new content is as following:

```
resource r0 {
     protocol "C";

  net {
    allow-two-primaries;
    after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
    after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
    after-sb-2pri disconnect;
  }
  on GROESSLTCL0A {
    device /dev/drbd0;
    disk /dev/sdb;
    address 163.104.8.108:7789;
    meta-disk internal;
   }

  on GROESSLTCL0B {
    device /dev/drbd0;
    disk /dev/sdb;
    address 163.104.8.107:7789;
    meta-disk internal;
  }

}
```

Then i recreated the resource:

```
drbdadm create-md r0
```

after that i restarted drbd service and all was working as expected.